# patent question

Tags: trademark, liability, patents

Hypothetical person is inventing a new product for sale. The product will include an ingredient that is patented and for sale for another use. They will buy their product and not change it but rather mix it with other ingredients and sell it for a different use than the original patented product. Do they need permission from the patent owner to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**No** - there is a doctrine called [patent exhaustion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_of_intellectual_property_rights). Once sold by the patentee or its licensee the buyer is free to do whatever they like without being encumbered by the patent. Of course your product might infringe some other patent or IP but a patent on a thing is exhausted after it is legitimately purchased.

To keep strings attached, the patent owner could lease the item under a restrictive contract rather than sell it outright.